# Rails render json validation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Two issues here.  First is that I need to access a model's id before all of its attributes are defined.  Meaning that this:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_presence_of :color_data

end
```

throws an error unless I removed the second line, which is not a good thing to do.  My second issue is that I don't want to render json until a model has both attributes.  This is my controller:

```
def create
    @search = Search.create( name: (params[:name]) )
    Resque.enqueue(InstagramWorker, @search.id)
    respond_to do |format|
            if @search.save
                format.json { render json: @search }
                format.html { redirect_to root_path }
            else
                format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        end     
    end 
end
```

Should I write some logic in the model to check for name && color_data before saving?  And is there a workaround for accessing an id without breaking validations?

Comment: you mean, like validate `:color_data` only sometimes?

Comment: Validate presence of color_data only after this:      Resque.enqueue(InstagramWorker, @search.id), which is where color_data is defined.  And then only render json if and when a search has a name AND color_data, but not before that.

Comment: You can't do that. Resque is asynchronous, so isn't guaranteed to finish before the end of your request cycle.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well the whole reason I trying this was because this process was timing out on Heroku, and the Heroku docs suggest using background jobs.  Back to square one...

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use conditional validations, like

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

```
validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :color_data, if: :some_condition?

private

def some_condition?
  # condition logic here
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

By calling `Resque.enqueue(InstagramWorker, @search.id)` you're telling resque to do something, but not as part of this request. So this could complete now, it could complete in 2 hours from now.

If you need to ensure that this completes before the request has finished, take it out of Resque.

What you could do is only validate the color_data on update, rather than create.  Presumably your resqueue job calls `@search.save`. So by adding

```
validates :color_data, presence: true, on: :update
```

But this wouldn't stop the json being rendered, you can't get past the fact that this is not part of the request without taking it out of resqueue.